# Phonegap build ipa not installing on 4S

Tags: ios, cordova, ipa

**What I Did:**
I have made an app for iphone using phonegap and signed it with distribution certificate and ad-hoc provisional profile.

**Problem Statement:**
In iTunes when i click on install and sync, it shows installing. But even after half an hour it will not install.
UDID of my device is present in provisional profile. What am i missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the answer to your question directly... I don't use itunes to load the app to a phone.

I think you should be using xcode to test the app on the phone...

Alternatively... you would use with phonegap build https://build.phonegap.com/ - just upload the certificate and a zip of your files... scan the qr code on your device and it will load!

Comment: i need to use ipa only because i have to distribute the app to others too

Comment: phonegap build will generate an ipa

Comment: I have successfully build an .ipa, it is installing successfully but it is not running. Any idea why I am facing this?